# How do I correctly use switches including the scanner utility?

Tags: java

I have been trying to figure out this code for a little while now and can't seem to fix it:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Graphs
{
 public void drawHistograms()// draws 5 histograms
 {
  Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

  int number1 = 0; // first number
  int number2 = 0; // second number
  int number3 = 0; // third number
  int number4 = 0; // fourth number
  int number5 = 0; // fifth number

  int inputNumber; // number entered by user
  int value = 0; // number of stars to print
  int counter = 1; // counter for current number

  while ( counter <= 5 )
  {
     System.out.println( "Enter number: " );
     inputNumber = input.nextInt();

     // define appropriate num if input is between 1-30
     if ( inputNumber >= 1 && inputNumber <= 30 )
     {
        switch ( inputNumber )
        {
           case 1:
              number1 = inputNumber;
              break; // done processing case

           case 2:
              number2 = inputNumber;
              break; // done processing case

           case 3:
              number3 = inputNumber;
              break;
           case 4:
              number4 = inputNumber;
              break; // done processing case

           case 5:
              number5 = inputNumber;
              break; // done processing case
        }counter++;

     } // end if
     else
        System.out.println(
           "Invalid Input\nNumber should be between 1 and 30" );
  } // end while

  // print histograms
  for ( counter = 0; counter <= 4; counter++ )
  {
     switch ( counter )
     {
        case 1:
           value = number1;
           break; // done processing case

        case 2:
           value = number2;
           break; // done processing case

        case 3:
           value = number3;
           break; // done processing case

        case 4:
           value = number4;
           break; // done processing case

        case 5:
           value = number5;
           break; // done processing case
     }

     for ( int j = 0; j <= value; j++ )
       {
        System.out.print( "*" );

       } System.out.println();       
  } // end for loop
} // end method drawHistograms
} // end class Graphs
```

My output is supposed to look like this:

```
Enter number: 5
Enter number: 2
Enter number: 8
Enter number: 4
Enter number: 6
*****
**
********
****
******
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this? I'm stumped. I've tried changing the variables in the switch to see what would change on the output; and I get almost the same thing no matter what I enter for a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the following two issues:

1. Your first `switch` should also switch on `counter` instead of on `inputNumber`.
2. For the loop surrounding your second `switch`, you should loop from 1 to 5 instead of 0 to 4.

---

On a side note: better to use a list or array to store your 5 numbers instead of using a separate variable for each.

Comment: Your first issue is the only thing I didn't catch and it was what i needed to get it to work the way I wanted it. I also understand that there are other ways to make the code shorter but I feel its a little too advance for me right now and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't need a `switch` here. Consider the following approach

```
public void drawHistograms() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] number = new int[5]; // define an array
    int inputNumber;
    int counter = 0; // set counter to 0
    while (counter <= 4) {
        System.out.println("Enter number: ");
        inputNumber = input.nextInt();
        if (inputNumber >= 1 && inputNumber <= 30) { // if input is valid
            number[counter] = inputNumber; // add that value to array
        } else {
            System.out.println("Number should be between 1 and 30");
        }
        counter++; // increment counter
    }
    // now your array contains all inputs
    for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) { // iterate array
        for (int j = 0; j < number[i]; j++) {// iterate up to element value
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: For this particular code I wanted to get used to using switches so I can get to learn them better but thanks for your input.